# Hide UserWarning from urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I use an opener with password manager and when I use my opener for the first time I've hot the following warning message :

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:894: UserWarning: Basic Auth Realm was unquoted
  url, req, headers)
```

My app seems to work fine, but how can I hide this message ?

PS: I use :

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
```

Comment: Check whether you could fix the server to produce correct realm. Related: http://bugs.python.org/issue12541

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`warnings` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) to filter out specific warnings in your code:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module='urllib2')
```